# Find a basis for $X\cap Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have two subspaces $X$ and $Y$:

$X = \{p \in P_2(\mathbb{R}): (4/3)a+c=0\}$

$Y = \{p \in P_2(\mathbb{R}): 3a+2b+c=0\}$

I have calculated that the basis of $X$ is $\{x^2−4/3,x\}$ and the basis of $Y$ is $\{x^2−3,x-2\}$ and I think these are correct, but I could be wrong.

Now I need to find a basis for $X\cap Y$. Would somebody be able to run me through this process? I know it has something to do with letting a vector $v$ be an element of both sets but I'm a bit stuck from there.

Thanks

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: You should solve: $\alpha (x^2-\frac{4}{3}) + \beta x = \gamma (x^2-3) + \delta (x-2),$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$ are scalars.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I guess it refers to the coefficients of the polynomial, $ax^2+bx+c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Am I right?

Your basis of $X$ and $Y$ are correct.

What is $X\cap Y$? It's$$\left\{ax^2+bx+c\,\middle|\,\frac43a+c=0\wedge 3a+2b+c=0\right\}.$$So, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac43a+c=0\\3a+2b+c=0.\end{array}\right.$$You'll get$$a=-\frac34c\text{ and }b=\frac58c.$$So take, for instance, the polynomial $p(x)=-6x^2+5x+8$. Then $X\cap Y=\mathbb{R}p(x)$ and $\bigl\{p(x)\bigr\}$ is a basis of $X\cap Y$.

Comment: Thanks. So $X\cap Y$ = $\{-6,5,8\}$ or does $X\cap Y$ = $\{-6x^2+5x+8\}$?

Comment: Correctly rephrasing that: Is  $\{-6,5,8\}$ a basis for $X\cap Y$ or is $\{-6x^2+5x+8\}$ a basis for $X\cap Y$?

Comment: @Shansss $\{-6x^2+5x+8\}$ is a basis of $X\cap Y$. The other possibility doesn't make sense, because *no* element of the set $\{-6,5,8\}$ belongs to $P_2(\mathbb{R})$.